# HTML - How do I reveal a checkbox group based on radio group?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to have an html form with a required radio group.
If one particular option in this radio group is selected, it reveals a checkbox group. This checkbox group should only be required if it is revealed.
How could I do this?
Preferably in pure HTML, but javascript can be used too if absolutely necessary.

Thanks

Comment: We're not a free coding service, you need to show what you've tried and tell us what you're stuck on.

Comment: Try to show some code or examples about what you have tried, and your issues. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```css
.checkbox-group {
  display: none;
}

[type=radio]:checked + .checkbox-group {
  display: block;
}

/*unneccessary*/
input { float: left;}
input[type=radio] { clear: both;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="val1">
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="val1_checkbox[]" value="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val1_checkbox[]" value="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val1_checkbox[]" value="3"/>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="val2">
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="val2_checkbox[]" value="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val2_checkbox[]" value="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val2_checkbox[]" value="3"/>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="val3">
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="val3_checkbox[]" value="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val3_checkbox[]" value="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="val3_checkbox[]" value="3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for your reference (HTML and Javascript):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var rad = document.myForm.radioBtnNm;
  var prev = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
   rad[i].onclick = function() {
    
    if (this.checked == true) {
     if (this.value == "check1") {
      document.getElementById("checkboxDiv1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("checkboxDiv2").style.display = "block";
     } else {
      document.getElementById("checkboxDiv1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("checkboxDiv2").style.display = "none";
     }
    }
   };
  }

 }
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <div id="radioDiv">
   <input type="radio" name="radioBtnNm" value="check1">Show
   Chckbox list 1<br> <input type="radio" name="radioBtnNm"
    value="check2">Show Chckbox list 2<br>
  </div>

  <div id="checkboxDiv1" style="display: none">
   <br> <label>Checkbox List 1</label> <br> <input
    type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="one"> One<br> <input
    type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="two"> Two<br> <input
    type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="three"> Three<br>
  </div>

  <div id="checkboxDiv2" style="display: none">
   <br> <label>Checkbox List 2</label> <br> <input
    type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="three"> Three<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="two"> Two<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="one"> One<br>
  </div>
 </form>
```